# How do i define variables from a try-except in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to make a simple BMI Calculator where user input is required. I used try-except for height and weight values to filter the inputs and avoid accepting string or less than 0 values. However, when I try to calculate for the bmi, it says that the value for height and weight are not defined.

```
`def height_main():
    height = 0
    while True:
        try:
            height_try = float(input("Enter your height in meters: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid height.")
            continue
        else:
            if height_try > 0:
                height += height_try
                break
            else: 
                ("Please enter a valid height.")
    return height

def weight_main():
    weight = 0
    while True:
        try:
            weight_try = float(input("Enter your weight in kilograms: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid weight.")
            continue
        else:
            if weight_try > 0:
                weight += weight_try
                break
            else: 
                ("Please enter a valid weight.")
    return weight

bmi = weight / (height**2)
print(bmi)`
```

This is the code I wrote. (Sorry if its messy, I'm new to coding and I'm just trying to recreate what I see on videos and other posts.)

when I try to run the code, this is what appears:

`NameError: name 'weight' is not defined`

I assumed the variables were already defined via the try-except. How can I define the values for height and weight?

Comment: you're using weight outside its scope. mind the indentation.

Comment: @RezaKeshavarz sorry if this will seem like a stupid question, but could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are referencing the variables inside of the methods from *outside* said method.

It doesn't exist because the variables are bound to the method's scope and not the global scope of your script.

Did you mean to perhaps call the methods like so?

```
bmi = weight_main() / (height_main()**2)
```